# How do I validate a field based on a value of another field in Angular Schema Form?

Tags: json, validation, angular-schema-form

I have a Form with 2 fields, postal code and country.
I need to validate postal code depending on country selection, using $validators

Here is the ngController code

```
$scope.schema = {
"type": "object",
"title": "my form",
"properties": {
  "postalCode": {
    "title": "Postal Code",
    "type": "string"
  },
  "countryCode": {
    "title": "Country",
    "type": "string",
    "enum": [
      "CA",
      "US"
    ]
  }
},
"required": [
  "countryCode"
]
};


  $scope.form = [{
  "key": "postalCode",
  $validators: {
        // I would like to pass countryCode as the argument but doesn't work because I don't have model in my closure
        postalCodeRegex: function (countryCodeValue) {
            if (angular.isString(countryCodeValue)) {                  
                var canada = "^(?!.*[DFIOQU])[A-VXY][0-9][A-Z]●?[0-9][A-Z][0-9]$";
                if (/canada/.test(countryCodeValue)) return true;
                else return false;
            }
            // if value is empty
            return true;
        }
    }
},
"countryCode", {
  "type": "submit",
  "style": "btn-info",
  "title": "OK"
}
];
```

is there another way to access model or scope from the $validators logic?

plunker link to see my code:
http://plnkr.co/edit/DDbMiw?p=info

Answer (score 0):

@houss You could use onChange to combine the values into a new value "US-90210", saved within a hidden field on a key added as part of the form, then validate on that hidden field with a regex covering both formats. Alternatively if you may need more than a few countries then I would use a directive which can be added via the add-on mechanisms. [Like the datepicker example but in the template add a component to do the heavy lifting](https://github.com/json-schema-form/angular-schema-form/blob/master/docs/extending.md#setting-up-schema-defaults)